# why are there symbol referencing errors when compiling in g++?

Tags: c++, g++

```
aludra.usc.edu(25): g++ -o final.out final.cpp 
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
data::Get_Networth()                /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Set_Networth(double)          /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Get_Heightfeet()              /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Get_Lettergpa()               /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Set_Weight(int)               /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Get_Weight()                  /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Get_Major()                   /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Set_Gpa(double)               /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Get_GPA()                     /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Set_Age(int)                  /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Get_Age()                     /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Set_Major(std::basic_string, std::allocator               >)/var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Set_Data(std::basic_string, std::allocator >,     int, int, int, double, std::basic_string, std::allocator >, double)/var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Get_Heightfeetremainder()     /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Set_Heightinches(int)         /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::data()                        /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Get_Name()                    /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
data::Get_Heightinches()            /var/tmp//ccUz9c59.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to final.out
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is what I keep getting in g++ when compiling in Solaris.
The code compiles perfectly in VS2010. So I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Here are my class file's code
data.h:

```
    #include <string>


using namespace std;
class data{
private:
string name;
int age;
int heightinches, heightfeet ,heightfeetremainder;
int weight;
double gpa;
char lettergpa;
string major;
double networth;


public:
//constructors
data();
//service functions
void Calc_heightfeet();
void Calc_lettergpa();
//Getter/Accessor functions
string Get_Name();
int Get_Age();
int Get_Heightinches();
int Get_Heightfeet();
int Get_Heightfeetremainder();
int Get_Weight();
double Get_GPA();
char Get_Lettergpa();
string Get_Major();
double Get_Networth();
//Setter/modifier functions
void Set_Data(string ,int , int ,int , double,string,double);
void Set_Age(int );
void Set_Heightinches(int );
void Set_Weight(int );
void Set_Major(string );
void Set_Gpa(double );
void Set_Networth(double );
};
```

data.cpp:

```
#include "data.h"
using namespace std;


//constructors
data::data(){;}
//service functions
void data::Calc_heightfeet()
{
    heightfeet= heightinches/12;
    heightfeetremainder= heightinches%12;
}
void data::Calc_lettergpa()
{
    if (gpa > 3.5)
            lettergpa= 'A';
    else if (gpa > 2.5)
            lettergpa= 'B';
    else if (gpa > 1.5)
            lettergpa= 'C';
    else if (gpa > .5)
            lettergpa= 'D';
    else
            lettergpa= 'F';
}
//Getter/Accessor functions
string data::Get_Name()
{
    return name;
}
int data::Get_Age()
{
    return age;
}
int data::Get_Heightinches()
{
    return heightinches;
}
int data::Get_Heightfeet()
{
    return heightfeet;
}
int data::Get_Heightfeetremainder()
{
    return heightfeetremainder;
}
int data::Get_Weight()
{
    return weight;
}
double data::Get_GPA()
{
    return gpa;
}
char data::Get_Lettergpa()
{
    return lettergpa;
}
string data::Get_Major()
{
    return major;
}
double data::Get_Networth()
{
    return networth;
}

//Setter/modifier functions
void data::Set_Data(string n,int a, int h,int w, double g,string m,double net)
{
    name=n;
    age=a;
    heightinches=h;
    weight=w;
    major=m;
    networth=net;
    gpa=g;
    Calc_heightfeet();
    Calc_lettergpa();   
}
void data::Set_Age(int a)
{
    age=a;  
}
void data::Set_Heightinches(int h)
{
    heightinches=h; 
    Calc_heightfeet();
}
void data::Set_Weight(int w)
{
    weight=w;
}
void data::Set_Major(string m)
{
    major=m;
}
void data::Set_Gpa(double g)
{
    gpa=g;
    Calc_lettergpa();   
}
void data::Set_Networth(double net)
{
    networth=net;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't seem to be compiling or linking `data.cpp`.  Try

```
g++ -o final.out final.cpp data.cpp
```

Comment: @user1363742 before you hide your face in embarrassment, give yourself credit for posting the command you used to compile the program and all of the output -- that was exactly what was necessary to find the problem.

Comment: @user1363742:  Remember to increase your reputation by **checking** answers that you like or find useful.